# How to retrieve a value from Widget

Tags: flutter, stateful

I'm very new to coding so i don't know too much, i'm sorry. I'm trying to get the value passed from screen 1 to screen 2, but the value is inside the widget from stateful. like that:

```
class Escrita extends StatefulWidget {


  List<Diario> _diarioupdate = <Diario>[];
  Escrita({Diario? teste});



  @override
  State<Escrita> createState() => _EscritaState();
}
```

and i want to retrieve the value teste that is passed from screen 1, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to access the `_diarioUpdate` inside your stateful widget. This can be accomplished  removing the underscore(_) from the _diarioupdate so that it won't be private member and then calling it inside the statefulwidget as `widget.diarioupdate`.

Answer (score 0):

in `_EscritaState` you can can call `widget._diarioupdate`.

for example you have `HomeWidget` as `StatefulWidget` that needs a `title`

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
```

you can access the `title` value using `widget` field in the `State` class

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title), // <----
      ),
      body: Container()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer. Thank you so much for helping. I solved like this:

```
Escrita({Diario? teste}){
this.teste};
```